# How to delete conversation with someone on Facebook, both from my inbox and from his inbox?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I have a conversation with someone on Facebook that contains some sensitive information that that person could use to harm me. What should I do to delete that conversation from both my inbox and from his inbox?

As far as I know, the delete option in Facebook only works for my inbox. That means that the messages I delete still remain in that person's inbox.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/227699513911093):

> No, sent messages can't be unsent or removed from the person's inbox. Depending on the persons's notification settings, they may also receive your message as an email notification.

Keep in mind that [deleting a conversation](https://www.facebook.com/help/192631610782421#How-do-I-delete-messages-or-a-conversation) from your inbox won't delete it from your friend's inbox. It isn't possible to delete sent or received messages from a friend's inbox.

Here is a workaround you can try. Report that sent message as Spam, and then delete it from your inbox. Now deactivate (don't delete) your profile for few hours and then reactivate. Probably that persons will not be able to see your message.

***Just a side note:*** In case that person already has saved your messages (via email notification or any other way), and try to harm you in future, do not hesitate to report this to cyber crime police immediately.