# Deleting Facebook Messenger messages for all users?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-messenger, facebook-privacy

I am attempting to regain my privacy by deleting some social media apps. I'm starting with Facebook and Messenger, because those are the ones I use the least, but I see that deactivating or deleting your Facebook account does not delete your Messenger messages for other users: the record remains. I would like to delete my presence completely, so, I have read these answers [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52532/how-can-i-delete-facebook-messages-sent-to-other-users?noredirect=1&lq=1) [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88415/how-can-you-mark-your-own-sent-messages-in-a-chat-as-spam-in-facebook?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/122363/how-to-delete-conversation-with-someone-on-facebook-both-from-my-inbox-and-from?noredirect=1&lq=1). I have a few questions:

- Do these methods even still work? These answers were given in 2015, 2016, and 2018, so are they still applicable now?
- Do I have to deactivate and reactivate my account, or can I just mark all my conversations as spam and then permanently delete my account? Is the reactivation mandatory for this method to work?
- Finally, do I mark the entire conversation thread as spam, or just my messages? Either way, how is that done?

Thank you in advance for helping me regain control of my privacy.